# Parallelization of EXP

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp, exp

Do you think it would be possible to calculate the exponential function using more than one thread? 
I have a code where the bottle neck is the calculation of `long double expl( long double )`. All the rest is already pretty much parallelized. I try several approximations but nothing worked so far.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: do you have memory constraints? if not I'd suggest a big LUT (look up table).

Comment: There are many options, depending on the accuracy you need.  Do you need *exactly* what `expl` would produce, or something reasonably close?

Comment: What exactly is your input for `expl`? Would it be possible to do something else instead?

Comment: Just curious. Since `exp` is common to most scientific codes are there any HW implementations of it?

Comment: if it really us your bottleneck try to utilize sse/avx/whatever and rebuild your app if possible to be data parallel. Use all tricks of trade (approximations for your function, no taylor approx., etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The calculation of `expl()` may well be your bottleneck, but a single evaluation of `expl()` is still going to consume a very small number of clock cycles. The overhead of performing thread synchronisation will outweigh any possible gain from parallel execution.